# How to get auto notifications to my application from docusign when ever recipient signs

Tags: docusignapi

Hi I am  requesting a signature from docusign using REST API in php. I can send mails successfully to recipient .my problem is I want to notified whenever signer signs the document. i mean in my application i want get auto notified when signer signs. is there any way to do that . what i have to do to get notifications . please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

DocuSign Connect is designed just for that.  DocuSign will make an HTTP POST request (or SOAP call) to your server and will give you a chunk of XML describing the current state of the envelope.

It can be triggered on various Envelope and Recipient events.  The Connect guide is here:  https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/connect-guide.pdf

(found here: https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation)